# Some pictures don't show up on my website

Tags: html, css

I have the website : http://alfer-ks.eu5.org/dyer_galeri.html , and as you can see, some pictures don't display at all, and mess all the alignment on the gallery. Their code is like this :

```
<div class="der1">
<a href="images/dyer/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[dyer]">
<img src="images/dyer/1.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="der2">
<a href="images/dyer/2.jpg" rel="lightbox[dyer]">
<img src="images/dyer/2.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
```

This goes on for all the images. I don't see the reason they won't show up. They work fine when I test them localy on my computer. And I haven't changed directories, I just zipped them and uploaded them all.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: Are the file paths using the correct case?

Comment: Getting a redirect to a placeholder on the link you provided - can you check that this works first (suggest you fix ASAP as this looks like spam). Other than that, try using the Chrome inspect tool (right click > inspect element) on the broken image to see if there's something wrong with the path. You could also use the "Network" tab on this tool to get an error code/check that you haven't made a mistake with the paths.

Comment: The link is working, and I found the solution. It was the images' fault. They were with the extension .JPG not .jpg in lowercase.

Comment: Yes, blame the images. Stupid images for going and changing their own extension like that ;)

Comment: The truth is that I used an image resizer, and that obviously changed them to uppercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've uploading from a operating system where case doesn't matter (probably Windows) to a server where it does matter (probably Linux)

You'll see that your broken image has a URL like

```
http://alfer-ks.eu5.org/images/dyer/12.jpg
```

[image: Broken image]

but what the file is actually called is

```
http://alfer-ks.eu5.org/images/dyer/12.JPG
```

[image: Working image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I figured it out myself, but nonetheless, this is the correct answer, and I'm marking it.

Comment: I am very curious why I can see the photo below with capital "PNG" extension while the the above photo shrinks into a light green icon.

Answer (score 1):

It is partly what elclanrs mentioned in his answer but not exactly.

From a quick browse i found that you reference:

```
http://alfer-ks.eu5.org/images/dyer/5.jpg
```

This image wont show on a linux or other case sensitive operating system since the actual image resides at:

```
http://alfer-ks.eu5.org/images/dyer/5.JPG
```

where the filename has `UPPERCASE` characters for the filetype `.jpg` therefore it should be referenced using `.JPG` and not `.jpg`.

You could either fix your links or try renaming all your images with lowercase filetypes.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, and I'm fixing the links. But Gareth was faster.

Comment: No problem. Problem solved is what matters... Who gets the accepted answer is secondary

Answer (score 0):

Well, the images don't show up because they don't actually exist in the server. Try tracing them with devtools and you'll get a 404.